# pandas grouper int by frequency

Tags: pandas

I would like to group a Pandas dataframe by hour disregarding the date.

My data:

```
id    opened_at             count   sum
      2016-07-01 07:02:05   1       46.14
154   2016-07-01 07:34:02   1       479
      2016-07-01 10:10:01   1       127.14
      2016-07-02 12:01:04   1       8.14
      2016-07-02 12:00:50   1       18.14
```

I am able to group by hour with date taken into account by using the following.

```
groupByLocationDay = df.groupby([df.id,
                                pd.Grouper(key='opened_at', freq='3h')])
```

I get the following

```
id    opened_at             count   sum
      2016-07-01 06:00:00   2       4296.14
154   2016-07-01 09:00:00   46      43716.79
      2016-07-01 12:00:00   169     150827.14
      2016-07-02 12:00:00   17      1508.14
      2016-07-02 09:00:00   10      108.14
```

How can I group by hour only, so that it would look like the following.

```
id    opened_at         count   sum
      06:00:00  2       4296.14
154   09:00:00  56      43824.93
      12:00:00  203     152335.28
```

The original data is on **hourly basis**, thus I need to get **3h frequency**.
Thanks!

Comment: does `groupByLocationDay = df.groupby([df.id, df['opened_at'].dt.hour])` work?

Comment: I need to get the freq='3h'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
In [134]: df
Out[134]:
    id           opened_at  count     sum
0  154 2016-07-01 07:02:05      1   46.14
1  154 2016-07-01 07:34:02      1  479.00
2  154 2016-07-01 10:10:01      1  127.14
3  154 2016-07-02 12:01:04      1    8.14
4  154 2016-07-02 12:00:50      1   18.14
5  154 2016-07-02 08:34:02      1  479.00

In [135]: df.groupby(['id', df.opened_at.dt.hour // 3 * 3]).sum()
Out[135]:
               count      sum
id  opened_at
154 6              3  1004.14
    9              1   127.14
    12             2    26.28
```

Comment: My data is on hourly basis, the Grouper has grouped it to 3 hour frequency by date already, if I try to use group by once more, I get KeyError: no attribute id or opened_at

Comment: Awesome thanks! I was thinking of using the grouper to group by 3 hour frequency, then reset the index and group again this time using your method. But this is way better.

Comment: @bumbambum, i'm glad to help! :) Thanks for accepting an answer!